# Is there a factor that modify your chance of stealing something?

Tags: octopath-traveler

When you have the thief in your party you can steal items from some pnj. You have a given pourcentage of chance to successfully steal each available item. I've noticed that for the healing grape at the moment I have a 80% success rate for the regular one and 8% for the upgraded one (in french it has a (M) next to it, for Medium I guess). I didn't see a difference when standing behind or in front of a pnj. So is there any factor that change your chance of stealing an item ?

Comment: Would like to know why someone downvoted this. It's not a bad question, they've shown some attempt to figure it out themselves and it's not blatantly against the rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your success rate increases as your thief's (Therion's) level increases.

There are also, in some towns, people that, if you scrutinize (with Cyrus) or inquire (with Alfyn) will give you an increased success rate. More specifically, when you do either of those actions you'll see "Thieving Tips & Tricks" in the "Information Gleaned" section of the dialog box.

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204212-octopath-traveler/76889313 lists all the towns that have an NPC that'll boost your steal success rate:

- Bolderfall - Townsperson (Near Entrance)
- Noblecourt - Townsperson (Near Book-loving Girl)
- Grandport - Elderly Woman (Inside the House with Blocked Entrance)
- Marsalim - Townsperson (Near Entrance)
- Northreach - Townsperson (Inside House, Higher Star rating)
- Riverford - Right Guard (Inside Tavern)

You can also kinda cheat by constantly restarting the game. In the Octopath community doing that is called "save scumming".

Comment: Alfyn is a hero path, so will never fail. What you probably mean is increase the probability of being attracted by primrose

Comment: @ForceGaia - no. "Thieving Tips & Tricks" is information that you need to glean. You can glean information with either Scrutinize or Inquire. Scrutinize can hurt your reputation in town whereas Inquire won't. The flip side is that you can glean information from higher level NPC's with Scrutinize, albeit with the risk that success is not guaranteed and failure will hurt your rep. Basically, you need to trigger the dialog box depicted in https://i.stack.imgur.com/v79J1.jpg

Comment: @ForceGaia - how would being attracted by primrose do anything to increase your stealing success rate anyway?

Comment: yeah, that was a misread, I was thinking you were making a comparison to the other Rouge actions with a chance of succeed/fail. I didn't make the link between them being the info-gathering actions. Pre-coffee brain is my excuse for not getting that